# How to disable the "--release" in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, release

Eclipse simply allows the flag to be toggled in setting, but gradle seems to have no way to suppress it. I tried setting the args exactly, and even setting source and target. Now gradle just complains that "source" and "--release" can't both be set at the same time.

```
compileJava
{
    options.compilerArgs    =   [
        '-source'           , '11'
    ,   '-target'           , '11'
    ,   '--patch-module'    , 'java.base=ALL-UNNAMED'
    ,   '--add-exports'     , 'java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Behaviour was fixed in Gradle 8.0. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/22449 for details.

Comment: The hint from https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-toolchain-but-building-java-8-bytecode/39350/7 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that this is what is generating that compiler argument. Removing it allowed me to proceed.

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set( JavaLanguageVersion.of(11) )
    }
}
```